# Sharing a globally defined db conn with multiple packages

Tags: go

I've read a few StackOverflow answers on how we handling the db connection. Since it's a pool, we can define it globally and use it in multiple goroutines and it's safe.

The issue I'm having is that I have split my REST API into multiple packages. Each of these packages require a db connection, so I open a database connection in the startup. But even if I define the connection globally, it's only at the package level. What can I do to potentially share it among multiple packages?

For some context I'm using the PostgreSQL driver and gin-gonic in my application.

Comment: By "packages" you mean different projects/libraries?

Comment: No, just internal packages.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

There is also the option of creating another package to hold your database connection-related settings. It can then have a package level global, which can be initialized in `main` and used in any package that is importing it.

This way, you can explicitly see that the database package is being imported. Here is some sample code.

```
package database

var (
    // DBCon is the connection handle
    // for the database
    DBCon *sql.DB
)
```

---

```
package main

import "myApp/database"

func main() {

    var err error
    database.DBCon, err = sql.Open("postgres", "user=myname dbname=dbname sslmode=disable")

}
```

---

```
package user

import "myApp/database"

func Index() {
    // database handle is available here
    database.DBCon

    ...
}
```

Comment: I kind of like this way. It seems a nicer way to move all database setup related stuff into that package.

Comment: Useful solution. How can one avoid import cycles though?

Comment: Is there a trick to store sql.Open statement in "database" package too?
that would be super neat.

Comment: @Angger if you just need to store the statement so it's called later, you can put a function inside of the var that, when called executes the defined sql.Open statement.

Comment: @Maaz, for this option, where would be an ideal place to handle ```defer database.DBCon.Close()```? Would this be on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: @gpanda I guess it depends, I'm treating this as a long lived connection. For example, if you're using gin-gonic or something you can detect if the server is receiving a shutdown signal and then close the database connection then, example: https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/examples/graceful-shutdown/graceful-shutdown/server.go

Comment: Can we use singleton pattern?

Comment: Mind blown! Is there a name for this pattern?

Answer (score 15):

Simple answer: pass an initialised connection pool to your packages' own globals.

e.g.

```
// package stuff

var DB *sql.DB

func GetAllStuff() (*Stuff, error) {
    err := DB.Query("...")
    // etc.
}

// package things

var DB *sql.DB

func GetAllThings() (*Thing, error) {
    err := DB.Query("...")
    // etc.
}

// package main

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("...")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    stuff.DB = db
    things.DB = db

    // etc.
}
```

We define package-level globals, make sure they're exported (capitalised) and then pass a pointer to our connection pool to them.

This is "okay", but can mask "where" things are being used. If you're looking at a handler it may not be clear *where* the connection is coming from, especially as your package grows. A more scalable approach might look like the below:

```
// package stuff

type DB struct {
    *sql.DB
}

func New(db *sql.DB) (*DB, error) {
    // Configure any package-level settings
    return &DB{db}, nil
}

func (db *DB) GetAllStuff() (*Stuff, error) {
    err := db.Query("...")
    // etc.
}

// package things

type DB struct {
    *sql.DB
}

func New(db *sql.DB) (*DB, error) {
    // Configure any package-level settings
    return &DB{db}, nil
}

func (db *DB) GetAllThings() (*Thing, error) {
    err := db.Query("...")
    // etc.
}

// package main

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("...")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    stuffDB, err := stuff.New(db)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    thingsDB, err := things.New(db)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Simplified.
    http.HandleFunc("/stuff/all", stuff.ShowStuffHandler(stuffDB))
    http.HandleFunc("/things/all", things.ShowThingsHandler(thingsDB))

    // etc.
}

func ShowStuffHandler(db *stuff.DB) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // We can use our stuff.DB here
        stuff, err := db.GetAllStuff()
        // etc.
    }
}
```

If you have more than just the DB connection as a dependency (e.g. config params, hostnames, etc.) , wrap them in an `things.Env` struct or a `stuff.Env` struct for each package.

An example would be to have a `things.New("deps...") *Env` function that returns a configured `*things.Env` that contains the dependencies used by your `things` package.

Comment: PS: I wrote an article on how to pass a struct with your handler or package dependencies: http://elithrar.github.io/article/http-handler-error-handling-revisited/ (an update on an older article) that might help you see it from another angle. Also see http://www.jerf.org/iri/post/2929 and https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/structuring-applications-in-go-3b04be4ff091 which are additional takes on these approaches.

Comment: Awesome, these are good. I kind of find it annoying that I have to pass in the db connection for each handler, but that makes it super explicit.

Answer (score 1):

***Update***

I've ended up using the `package config` to initialize database, at the start of the application, It's pretty good, as you don't have to pass any unneeded param to functions.

---

***Original***

I'm still new to the golang world, but I'm handling this same problem, by declaring
local variables in the main package, in my case its `package app`

```golang
var mongoClient *mongo.Client
var mongoCtx context.Context
var mongoCancelCtx context.CancelFunc
```

then I'm passing them to a database file inside `package config` to connect to the database, and use the passed pointer to assign the result.

```golang
# app/app.go

var mongoClient *mongo.Client
var mongoCtx context.Context
var mongoCancelCtx context.CancelFunc
config.BootstrapDatabase(&mongoClient, &mongoCtx, &mongoCancelCtx)
```

```golang
# app/config/database.go

// BootstrapDatabase ...
func BootstrapDatabase(mongoClient **mongo.Client, ctx *context.Context, cancel *context.CancelFunc) {
    *ctx, *cancel = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)

    client, err := mongo.Connect(*ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI(os.Getenv("MONGO_URI")))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := client.Ping(*ctx, readpref.Primary()); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    *mongoClient = client

    fmt.Println("Successfully connected and pinged.")
}
```

Then I'm creating a database reference and passing it to each package
that will make use of it.

```golang
# app/app.go

db := mongoClient.Database(os.Getenv("MONGO_DATABASE"))
repositories.BootstrapRepositories(db)

e := echo.New()
routes.BootstrapRoutes(e, db)
```

So the idea is to declare the database reference in the high level package which is my `app/app.go` in my app and pass it down as needed, for example in my `package routes`

```golang
#app/app.go


// BootstrapRoutes ...
func BootstrapRoutes(e *echo.Echo, db *mongo.Database) {

    // Set middleware
    e.Use(middleware.Logger())
    e.Use(middleware.Recover())

    // Users related routes
    e.POST("/api/users", controllers.CreateUser)

    // Starte web server
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":4242"))
}
```

I'm still experimenting with it, I don't know yet if this approach will skill
with many endpoints, or I need to try separating it into its own package, as suggested in the first thread of this issue.

Please share you thoughts I'll be happy to hear from you.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something like this. Each configuration file contains its own connection method and exports a global variable.

### main.go

```golang
func main() {

    var cors = handlers.CORS(
        handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"}),
        handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"Content-Type", "x-api-key"}),
        handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"POST","GET", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"}),
    )

    server := &http.Server{
        Handler:      cors(apiRouter.Router),
        Addr:         "0.0.0.0:80",
        WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }

    if os.Getenv("STATUS") == "dev" {
        server.Addr = "0.0.0.0:3000"
    }

    // configuration
    configs.ConfigureS3()
    configs.ConnectRedis()
    configs.ConfigureDb()

    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
}
```

and in my configs package there are three files:

### configs/mysql.go

```golang
var Db *sql.DB

func ConfigureDb() {
    var err error

    mysqlConfig := &mysql.Config{
        User:   os.Getenv("MYSQL_USER"),
        Net: "tcp",
        Passwd: os.Getenv("MYSQL_PASSWORD"),
        Addr:   os.Getenv("MYSQL_HOST"),
        DBName: os.Getenv("MYSQL_DATABASE"),
    }

    Db, err = sql.Open(
        "mysql",
        mysqlConfig.FormatDSN(),
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Db connection configuration
    Db.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Minute * 5)
    Db.SetMaxOpenConns(1000)
    Db.SetMaxIdleConns(1000) // I have to always set it to greater or equal to max open connection
}
```

### configs/redis.go

```golang
var RedisPool *redis.Pool

func ConnectRedis() {
    RedisPool = &redis.Pool{
        MaxIdle:     3,
        IdleTimeout: 3 * time.Minute,
        Dial: func() (redis.Conn, error) {
            return redis.Dial(
                "tcp",
                os.Getenv("REDIS_HOST") + ":" + os.Getenv("REDIS_PORT"),
                redis.DialPassword(os.Getenv("REDIS_PASSWORD")),
            )
        },
    }
}
```

### configs/aws.go

```golang
var S3Client *s3.Client

func ConfigureS3() {
    awsConfig, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    S3Client = s3.NewFromConfig(awsConfig)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For initialize a package-scoped value (here a database connection), just defined a variable with package scope.

In a `init()` function as `main()`, describe how to initialize the variable.

```golang
package database

var db *sql.DB

func init(){
  db, err = sql.Open("credentials")
  if err != nil{
    panic(err)
  }
}

// Getter for use everywhere else package
func DB()*sql.DB{
  return db
}
```

Go automatically execute `init()` function while importing the library and before `main()` function.

In you `main.go` file, import as dependancies as

```golang
package main

import _ "../folder/database" // init() have been executed, and initialize db

func main(){}
```