# Oracle (godror) open connections exceed the maximum allowed

Tags: oracle, go

I am using go 1.13 and `godror` (the former `goracle`) package as a driver to access my `oracle` database. I follow the recommended precautions and establish my connections safe and sane. There are cases, however, that I see some weird misbehaviors with my `go app`, my host **CentOS**, and my `oracle` database.
[image: Number of open connections in normal behavior]

I have set my connections not to surpass 50, and through its normal usage it observes it. But, in some cases in which the database is busy making some costly reports, I see this number exceed way beyond the pre-set maximum. For instance, the number of open connections reaches 10000!

[image: App's open database connections during abnormal cases]

Here is my connection string:

```
user=user password=secret connectString=oracle_host:1521/testdb configDir=
connectionClass= enableEvents=0 heterogeneousPool=0 libDir= newPassword= poolIncrement=1
poolMaxSessions=50 poolMinSessions=0 poolSessionMaxLifetime=1h0m0s poolSessionTimeout=42s
poolWaitTimeout=0s prelim=0 standaloneConnection=0 sysasm=0 sysdba=0 sysoper=0
timezone=local
```

Auxiliary info:  I open my database connection once in a package and open it, then we use this instance elsewhere in the app. One can see the code [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/d-fal/7aae6c5b08264b92ebdc9be4c7e98c2b)

References:

- [Connection openning in godror](https://godror.github.io/godror/doc/connection.html)
- [Sharing database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31228542/3741686)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend starting by setting `db.SetMaxIdleConns(0)` so that you use only the Oracle pool, and not both the Oracle pool and the database/sql pool at the same time.

Comment: Thank you Christopher, your suggestion was echoed in the docs as well. I apply it or try to upgrade my go to > 1.14. Will update my question if it resulted in any good stance.

Comment: Update: I made some changes as per your recommendation. I still encounter cases that open the number of connections exceed the limit, say 50, but this time it doesn't reach to 8000 and above. Besides, it does not go to the stall and closes extra connections in the spur of a minute. Should I consider this issue as resolved?

Comment: The extra connections could be transient if you are changing some state?? You could open an issue on [Github](https://github.com/godror/godror/issues) but will need to give a runnable program.